# Maximal cardinality of $(n,2^{-k})$-separated set and minimal cardinality of $(n,2^{-k})$-spanning set

Tags: dynamical-systems, entropy, symbolic-computation

Let $A$ be some finite alphabet and consider the set
$$
X=\{x=(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\in A^{\mathbb{Z}}: x_i\in A\forall i\in\mathbb{Z}\}
$$
of bi-infinite sequences with entries in $A$. On $X$, I am considering the left-shift map defined by
$$
(\sigma(x))_i=x_{i+1}.
$$

Moreover, on $X$, define the metric
$$
d(x,y)=2^{-k}
$$
with $k$ maximal such that $x_{[-k,k]}=y_{[-k,k]}$. Here 
$$x_{[-k,k]}=(x_{-k},\ldots,x_{-1},x_0,\ldots,x_1,\ldots,x_k),$$
is the central block of length $2k+1$ around position $0$.

The convention is that $k=-1$ if $x_0\neq y_0$ and $k=\infty$ if $x=y$.

Define 
$$
d_n(x,y):=\max_{0\leq i\leq n-1}d(\sigma^i(x),\sigma^i(y)).
$$

Let $\varepsilon >0$. 
A set $E\subset X$ is called $(n,\varepsilon)$-separated if for all $x,y\in E, x\neq y$, we have
$$
d_n(x,y)>\varepsilon.
$$
By $\text{sep}(n,\varepsilon)$ denote the maximal cardinality of an $(n,\varepsilon)$-separated set.

A set $E\subset X$ is called $(n,\varepsilon)$-spanning, if for all $x\in X$ there exists some $y\in E$ such that
$$
d_n(x,y)\leq\varepsilon.
$$
By $\text{spa}(n,\varepsilon)$, denote the minimal cardinality of a $(n,\varepsilon)$-set.

**My question**

> For $(X,d)$ as defined above, I am searching for $\text{sep}(n,2^ {-k})$, i.e. the maximal cardinality of an $(n,2^{-k})$-separated set, and $\text{spa}(n,2^{-k})$ i.e. the minimal cardinality of an $(n,2^{-k})$-spanning set.

By $B_n(X)$, I denote the set of all blocks of length $n$ which can occur in elements $x\in X$.

My idea is that
$$
\text{spa}(n,2^{-k})=\text{card}(B_{2k+n})
$$
and
$$
\text{sep}(n,2^{-k})=\text{card}(B_{2k+n}),
$$
i.e. both numbers coincide and equal the number of blocks of length $2k+n$ which can occur in elements of $X$.

Am I right? Would be nice to get some feedback.

Comment: Since you don't give any reason for "My idea is that" you really cannot expect much help, since after all you are the one interested in the question. Anyways, it is a simple exercise to show that both the maximum and the minimum are equal to that cardinal, up to universal constants. On the other hand, the problem seems to have little interest since there are many **nonequivalent** distances giving the same topology on $X$. Since the interest is the entropy, why should we care about such precise information? Universal constants are quite fine.

Comment: What do you mean with Universal Constants?

Comment: Independent of $n$ and $k$.